# php: I want a code to be executed every 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, database, automation

I will try be clear and specific :)

So i have a website, where people purchase stuff from each other.
To keep everything organised, when someone buys something from another user, That purchase will be moved to a table in database, called Pending. (Note: The purchased is not processed yet)

(so all purchases will be moved and queued into this 'Pending' table)

Now what I want to do is, that this table 'Pending', starts processing 1 purchase at a time automatically (let's say 1 purchase every one minute --> if there are any ofcourse).

Now I have no idea how to do this, if someone can atleast give me a hint on what can I use or what to look for, in order to do this.

Note: am using php & mysql

Thanks in advance :D :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a PHP script to be executed by [a cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).  PHP doesn't have to be executed from a browser request, it can be [run form the command-line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).  Cron would make use of this functionality.

The crontab line to execute a command every minute would be as follows:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.php
```

Each column has a `*` indicating "any value", so this indicates to run the script "any minute, any hour, any day, any month, any day of week"

Comment: Just remember that php configuration for cli may be different than the one for the web. With cron you can also make "browser like" request with wget or curl if cli causing problems

Comment: well, it's the first time I hear of the cron job scheduler, so am reading about it right now :-), There are few questions I need to find the answers for.

Comment: For exmaple: this job scheduler is provided by hosting companies? (my hosting company is bluehost), and how to exactly use it :)

Comment: @Shady: That's a question for your hosting provider.  They might not have such functionality, in which case you'd have to ask them what kind of job scheduling functionality they _do_ have?  If you're not using a server that you control, then you're going to have to talk to the server's admin.

Comment: I found a tutorial for setting it up , at bluehost.com :-), thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

A cronjob is going to be your best bet, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

Make some file named MovePending.php with a MySQL query that 'moves' the purchases from Pending to Processed, and run it every minute via a cron job.

Comment: Hey m8, am new to stackoverflow, I think you get notified when I add a comment to your answer :P, atleast I hope so :-)

Comment: I did create a page on my website called cronscript.php , am having trouble though writing a readable command for cron to run the page, time set up also was successful, will rly appreciate if you can help me with it, or give me a clue where to look :-) thank you, I simply have no idea about unix-like programs

Comment: Paste it in here using the ticks ` `, let me see what you've done ;o